# Why the following code is not working?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, win32-process

I have Created a static control using following styles...

```
picBoxDisp = CreateWindow("STATIC", "image box",
         WS_VISIBLE |WS_CHILD | SS_BITMAP |WS_TABSTOP | WS_BORDER,
         50, 50, 250, 300,
         hwnd , (HMENU)10000, NULL, NULL);  

SetWindowLongPtr(picBoxDisp,GWLP_WNDPROC,(LONG) dispWndProc);
```

from someplace in my program I have the following code..

```
SendMessage(picBoxDisp,STM_SETIMAGE, (WPARAM) IMAGE_BITMAP,(LPARAM) hBitmap);
```

now inside the dispWndProc I have the following code..

```
LRESULT CALLBACK dispWndProc(HWND hwnd,UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
static HDC hdc;
static PAINTSTRUCT paintSt;
static RECT aRect;
switch(msg)
{
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd,&paintSt);
        GetClientRect(hwnd,&aRect);                     
        // the code for painting 
        EndPaint(hwnd,&paintSt);
    }
    break;
    case STM_SETIMAGE:
    {

        //painting code;
        HBITMAP img = (HBITMAP)lParam;
        BITMAP bmp;
        GetObject(img,sizeof(bmp),&bmp);
        HDC imgDC = GetDC((HWND)img);
        HDC memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(imgDC);
        SelectObject(memDC,img);
        if((img==NULL))// ||(imgDC==NULL)||(memDC==NULL))
        {

                     MessageBox(NULL,"img is NULL","Bad Programming!!! Error",MB_OK);

        }

        else

        {
        StretchBlt(hdc,0,0,aRect.right,aRect.bottom,
        memDC,0,0,bmp.bmWidth,bmp.bmHeight,
        SRCCOPY);
        }

    }
        break;  
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd,msg,wParam,lParam);

}

return 0;
}
```

**can anyone tell why the lParam doesnt typecast back to HBITMAP.... why img is NULL ?**

thanks in advance,

Comment: Why subclass a Static control instead of just creating your own class? Generally you don't subclass another control unless you want to use and customize some of its existing functionality. Doing the painting code in STM_SETIMAGE is odd; typically you'd just store away the bitmap handle and call InvalidateRect, and then do all painting in WM_PAINT. Also; in SetWindowLongPtr, cast to LONG_PTR, not LONG; casting to LONG may casue this code to fail when compiled for win64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that some other code is also sending `STM_SETIMAGE` to your window.  Count the number of times you call `SendMessage(STM_SETIMAGE)` and the number of times you reach `case STM_SETIMAGE`.

---

Also, `HDC imgDC = GetDC((HWND)img);` is never going to work.  An `HBITMAP` is not an `HWND`.

Comment: I am sending STM_SETIMAGE just once in whole program (The line I wrote above)....

Comment: @Arts: And what about code you didn't write?  The OS sends messages to windows all the time, for a wide variety of reasons.

Comment: @Ben Voigt : please see the edited code, This is a static box inside a child panel of the main window. I dont know how to fix it. The API of the SendMessage() and STM_SETIMAGE says that lParam has handle of the image send and the code was working fine before I added a separate WNDPROC for this static control. I am new in WIN32, just cant find the error..... Nyway thanks buddy for your help..

Comment: @Arts: You don't.  An `HBITMAP` doesn't have a DC.  A DC has an `HBITMAP`, which can be swapped using `SelectObject`.  You already have that.  Try saving the `HBITMAP` handle in `STM_SETIMAGE` and doing everything else in `WM_PAINT`.  Get rid of `GetDC` and use `memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc)`.

Comment: @Ben : ok... and thanks for your help now the only problem is why the variable img is NULL ?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues with this code.

1. You cannot use `BeginPaint` / `EndPaint` anywhere except for handling `WM_PAINT`. Fix that before even considering other problems.
2. Next, it's not clear that you're correctly subclassing the window; make sure you call `CallWindowProc` on the old window proc.
3. It's tricky to guarantee that what you are seeing is really what you think you are seeing. For example as Ben Voigt says, maybe you are not the one that sent it. Maybe a switch case block above fell through. Maybe you passed in `NULL` to begin with.

Start with these things, and you will get closer to being on track.

Comment: As per your suggestions I have edited the code, but the variable img is still NULL... and How do I get the DC of a HBITMAP object... thanks for ur time.

Comment: You are still not calling `CallWindowProc`. `DefWindowProc` is not the same at all; the control will not function without the correct subclassing technique.

Comment: ok than where should I use CallWindowProc . in the default section ? and which WNDPROC should I call the dispWndProc (WNDPROC of static control), child1WndProc(the WNDPROC of the panel which owns the static control) or MyWndProc(which is the parent of the child window in turn)..... I am really new in WIN32..Thanks once again..

Comment: @TheAmitKumar: You should call the old window proc, which you replaced during subclassing.  Better yet, you should subclass with [`SetWindowSubclass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762102.aspx) and call [`DefSubclassProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776403.aspx).